# Proper programming practice

Tags: java

Generically the issue is how to pass a list of ItemStacks to the method of a class so I don't have to pass 20 different ItemStacks. ItemStack is defined here: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.html

So, how does one create a list or array of ItemStacks?

```
ItemStack stack1 = new ItemStack();
ItemStack stack2 = new ItemStack();
```

does not work but need something like:

```
ItemStack[] stacks = new ItemStack[];
stacks = {stack1, stack2};
```

so I can:

```
DisplayInventory.open(stacks);
```

Instead of:

```
DisplayInventory.open(stack1, stack2);
```

Solved.

My problem was that I was trying to perform an assignment outside of a method.

```
public class SomeClass {
    // you can instantiate here
    ArrayList<ItemStack> stack = new ArrayList<>();
    // but you cannot assign here
    stack.add(whatever); // this produces an error

    void method() {
        stack.add(whatever); // this works just fine
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the intent of your pseudo-code.  Could you show actual Java code?

Comment: (off-topic advice): the Java naming convention is `UppercaseStartingCamelCase` for classes, so you should name things `WhateverController`, `WhateverModel`.  Methods are written as `lowercaseStartingCamelCase()`.

Comment: I feel like the text and the code are for two different questions. Maybe it's me, but this confuses the heck out of me. Can you clarify your question and your code for us? Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to perhaps help you to improve your current and future questions.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I didn't know that but will do from now on. Your suggestion is very welcome as im still adjusting to Java.

Comment: Even after the edit, `ItemStack` is not mentioned anywhere in the code. Please try to post everything relevant in order to make the question answerable.

Comment: as @MickMnemonic says, and I'll add, "...and coherent."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is still not very clear, but I believe that what you are looking for is [Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). Varargs allow you to pass an arbitrary number of the same class to a method, so that they are available in that method as an array. For example:

```
public void doSomethingMethod(String... arrayOfStrings) {
    for (String string : arrayOfStrings) {
        // Do something with the string
    }
}
```

The above method can be called with any number of strings, including zero, and the enhanced for loop will do something with each string that is passed. Those strings can be string variables, string literals, and even string arrays:

```
doSomethingMethod();  // Works, but does nothing
doSomethingMethod("John"); // Does something with John
doSomethingMethod("John", "Steve"); // Does something with John and Steve
String[] names = new String[100];
for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    // add names into names
}
doSomethingMethod(names); // Does something with 100 names.
```

However, it does not work with collections. They must be converted to arrays.

```
doSomethingMethod(myArrayList); // Does not compile
doSomethingMethod(myArrayList.toArray(new String[0]); // Does something with every String 
                                                      // in myArrayList
```

The "..." after `String` in the method declaration is the magic that lets you use any number of parameters of the same class. To do this for your ItemStacks, it should be something like:

```
public void doSomethingMethod(ItemStack... arrayOfItemStacks) {
    for (ItemStack itemStack : arrayOfItemStacks) {
        // Do something with itemStack
    }
}

(...)

doSomethingMethod(itemStack1, itemStack2);

ItemStack[] itemStacks = new ItemStack[100];
// Assign 100 ItemStacks to itemStacks
doSomethingMethod(itemStacks);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I tried to do but instead of using the type string, im trying to do the same thing with the type ItemStack however it does not work with ItemStack so I need a work around.

Essentially I need a way to make an array of ItemStack.

Comment: Why doesn't it work with ItemStack? It should. Just replace String with ItemStack.

Comment: Can you provide a working example of adding itemstacks to the itemstack array? every way I tried failed.

Comment: I edited the example to use ItemStacks. There shouldn't be any difference. String and ItemStack are both Objects, and should behave the same way in arrays, with the exception that you can have String literals but not ItemStack literals.

Comment: I did try that but didn't have "[100 ]". Will try again but last time I tried there was no way to add. So for example itemStacks.add or itemStacks =+ stack1. Maybe this is because I did not have the 100 in "new ItemStack[100]".

Comment: Then use however many you have. Arrays are of fixed size, and that size must be declared before you can start putting things into them. If you don't know how many you are going to have, use `ArrayList<ItemStack> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>()` instead. Then you can use `myArrayList.add(stack1)` for as many as you have. Then call your varargs method as `doSomethingMethod(myArrayList.toArray(new ItemStack[0]));`

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a go in a few hours and get back to you with how it went.

Comment: Ok, I entered the following code:
  ArrayList<ItemStack> stack = new ArrayList<>();
  stack.add(stat1);

now in eclipse, normally when I would type stack and put a full stop, it should give me options but when I typed stack and put a full stop, no options displayed. further upon completing the assignment stack.add(stat1); the full stop and the variable stat1 are underlined. Also when I hover my mouse over stat1, it say's it wants me to insert a variable declairoid.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what I was doing wrong. Apparently you cant do this outside of a method. I will update my main post with this info.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the reputation points to upvote your answer but thanks all the same. XD